# How to create pyramid of asterisks in asp

Tags: asp-classic

```
<%

For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 5 < i to 5 step -1
        response.write(" ")
    Next

    for k = 0 < i to 10
        response.write("*")
    Next

    response.write("</br>")
Next
%>
```

above my code to create asterisk pyramid using asp classic. the result below:

[image]

how to make the solution to create asterisk pyramid below:

[image]

Comment: solved by my self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%

For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 to i
        response.write(j)
    Next

    for k = 0 < i to 10
        response.write(" ")
    Next

    response.write("</br>")
Next
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 to i
        response.write(j)
    Next

    for k = i to 10 '<-- fill the rest of the blanks
        response.write(" ")
    Next

     response.write("</br>")
Next
%>
```